# Mongoid: can I embed many and reference one of the embedded?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a list of games. Each one has an embedded list of scores. I'd like to keep a reference to the best score outside of the scores list.

```
class Game
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :best_score_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
  ... 
  embeds_many :scores

class Score 
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :user, type: String
  field :score, type: Int
```

I tried doing an `belongs_to` and a `has_one` but got an error message: "Referencing a Score document from the Game document via a relational association is not allowed since the price history is embedded." I suppose I can store the relevant bits of the Score in a hash called "best_score" but it makes more sense to me to embed many scores and then reference one of them as "Best". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this -

Write a method to pick the best score in the game model class -

```
def best_score
  score = scores.order_by(:score, :desc).limit(1)
  if score.nil?
    nil
  else
    score.first
  end
end
```

And since scores are embedded in the game, there won't be any +1 query to the database also.

Comment: I don't really want to load the scores until I need them, it's a pretty large array (the real object array is much larger than the sample I put in my post).

Comment: If most of the times you only need a single best score I think you should write a map-reduce that query out only a single best score along with the field you require. Or you might want to use referenced instead of using embedded to load the scores later when you actually needed.

Comment: > that query out only a single best score along -- right, but then I guess I'd have to store it as a hash... Just seems odd that I can't do a ref and embed in the same object.

Comment: This is what I think, if it's referenced it will query out (doing one more query) a single top score. But if it's embedded, all scores are already came out along with the game document, so I think the above method will sort and give the single top one out.

Comment: @jcollum "right, but then I guess I'd have to store it as a hash... Just seems odd that I can't do a ref and embed in the same object." If you store it as hash you will have to write a mechanism to update the best score value everytime you add or delete the data.